# How to allow setting of session variable only on initial page load OR when exists on request?

Tags: php, session-variables

I want to define **only** once, on the page load, the session variable $SESSION_estatus.  Then I want to update it ONLY when a request variable is passed on the URL.  Currently if the $_REQUEST['estatus'] variable is not present, it is updating the $SESSION_estatus back to all.  In other words, I am trying to maintain the state of the selection of $SESSION_estatus when it is not being passed on the URL.  I hope that makes more sense.

My code

```
if(! isset($SESSION_estatus) ){
       $SESSION_estatus = 'all';    
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['estatus'])){
       $SESSION_estatus = $_REQUEST['estatus'];
}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session variable is $_SESSION, I hope that helps you

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['estatus']) ){
   $_SESSION['estatus'] = 'all';    
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['estatus'])){
   $_SESSION['estatus'] = $_REQUEST['estatus'];
}
```

Comment: thanks, your syntax of the session variable was the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the question. Hope this helps

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['estatus']))
{
     if(! isset($_SESSION['estatus']) ){
       $_SESSION['estatus'] = 'all';    
     }else{
     $_SESSION['estatus'] = $_REQUEST['estatus'];
     }
}
```

Comment: that wont work because if(isset($_REQUEST['estatus'])) will not be true upon initial page load.....